# get rows that were excluded by sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is there any fast way to get rows that are excluded by a query.  For instance I run:

```
select * from tblUsers where user_type = 3
```

I'm looking for a fast to get the rows that were excluded by this query.

I understand I can easily change the where clause, but some queries are very complex and take some time to change.  With lots of large queries, this task can take very long to do by hand.

Comment: Do these large queries have similar columns?

Comment: 9 views, must be somethings good for lunch today.

Comment: i don't get it. Why not run the query for the results you actually want?

Comment: @CalvinSmith Its really for data analysis and sometimes debugging.

Comment: I mean, I somewhat understand. But if your running a query for something, if you want the not records, you can mirror the query. The concept is just weird to me. With SQL you can get almost any dataset you want, so you want to return something thats not selected. Just search for the not selected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dump the results of your super complex query into a temporary table.

ex.

```
create table #Temp
(
First varchar(50),
Last varchar(50)
)
go
select * from #Temp
```

then do a join off the original data to get what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

For an actual exclusion, you could do:

```
select * from tblUsers

EXCEPT

select * from tblUsers where user_type = 3
```

But why not just do

```
select * from tblUsers where user_type <> 3
```

Comment: how would `EXCEPT` be faster than a `not` clause ?

Comment: It shouldn't be, which is why I recommend the <> 3 method.

Comment: 3VL! `select * from tblUsers where (user_type <> 3 OR user_type IS NULL)`

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from tblUsers 

EXCEPT

select * from tblUsers where user_type = 3
```